# My facebook redirect to localhost

Tags: redirection, hosts

I am in strange condition right now. I am not able to access facebook.

Once I open the facebook it just loads the localhost.

I know we can set it from host file. But just have a look at my host file. There is nothig which redirects facebook to localhost. Is there any other way we can set this redirection? I am on windows 7.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#127.0.0.1 local
```

[image: Ping facebook.com]
[image: NS Lookup]

Comment: Wouldn't that be a good thing not to be able to log onto Facebook?

Comment: Are you sure your company isn't blocking this?

Comment: @ceejayoz have just talked with them, but they are not blocking that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

- hosts file (you already tried)
- DNS Cache (clear it with ipconfig /flushdns)
- DNS Server (check it with nslookup as posted above)

probably the "ipconfig /flushdns" will solve the problem as your DNS Server should have the proper records.

also dont forget to check your DNS Server settings

ipconfig /all should show those, they need to be reachable.

Comment: how to run "iptables /flushdns"? As I am getting "Windows can not find iptables"

Comment: you can run the iptables command in a command box (cmd.exe)

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns is executing that I have tried but iptables not working..

Comment: What are you talking about? `iptables` is the interface to netfilter on most Linux distributions. It's not a Windows application and even on Linux, it doesn't have anything to do with the DNS cache.

Comment: Very sorry, I ment ipconfig. changed the answer (fail /me for doing both linux and windows randomly)

Comment: @MarkM I am not sure how but. now I am able to access facebook with www but without www its redirecting to localhost. How can this possible.

Comment: @Avinash I didn't answer your question, so I don't know why you're pinging me. That said, www.facebook.com is a subdomain and can be resolved entirely different from facebook.com if you have a borked setup.